# Rotate center of image using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm not sure if I'm doing it right but I want to rotate a circular image around its center...this is my attempt so far. When I try to run this it just opens a black pygame screen that closes off immediately and doesn't tell me what the problem is

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # """Initialize a new game"""
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pygame.init()

        # set up a 640 x 480 window
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        # load image
        self.img = pygame.image.load("basketball.png")

        # use a white background
        self.bg_color = 255, 255, 255

        # Setup a timer to refresh the display FPS times per second
        self.FPS = 30
        self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)

    def run(self):
        #"""Loop forever processing events"""
        running = True

    def rot_center(image, rect, angle):
        # Rotate function
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
        rot_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center=rect.center)
        return rot_image, rot_rect

        rect = self.img.get_rect()
        self.img2 = rot_center(self.img, rect, 90)

        while running:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            # player is asking to quit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            # time to draw a new frame
            elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
                self.draw()
            else:
                pass # an event type we don't handle            

    def draw(self):
        # Update the display
        # everything we draw now is to a buffer that is not displayed
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

        rect = self.img.get_rect()
        rect = rect.move(self.width//2-rect.width//2, self.height//2-rect.height//2)

        self.screen.blit(self.img2)

        # flip buffers so that everything we have drawn gets displayed
        pygame.display.flip()


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: 1) You never call `rot_center` 2) You want the running loop outside of `rot_center` and call `rot_center` in the loop

Answer (score 2):

1. You never call `rot_center`
2. You want the `while running:` loop outside of `rot_center` (perhaps in `run`) and call `rot_center` in the loop

Specifically, put the while running loop in run, since that's what you want it to do, run the loop. Then in the second elif, call rot _ center before you refresh the frame. And take out the recursive call to rot_center, otherwise you'll never get out of the recursive calls

Comment: Hey thank you and one more question, how would you call it in the loop? Just use an extra elif statement? @CDspace

Comment: @hurt see edit, it should be enough to get you on track

Answer (score 1):

So, **init** is called, then run() is called, then pygame is closed, then the program exits. You need to end up in an event loop.